# How to increase Security Group Rules Limit for an EC2 (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, system-administration, aws-security-group

I created another SG and attached to the same VPC, but that won't work. The only alternative I see for now is to attach another network interface with a pubIP and add the second SG there. Is any way of increasing the limit of first SG rules limit in the primary network interface of the instance.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide more details about your situation? For example, what is the problem you are experiencing? Is it that you have reached the capacity of the number of rules in a single Security Group? Have you tried creating a second security group and attaching it to the same instance? Why do you have so many rules — are you adding individual IP addresses or are you using larger CIDR ranges? Anything more you can tell us will help us give you a good answer!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have an EC2 instance with a public IP and one (primary) network interface, and I need to add a bunch of rules in the security group attached to the primary network interface, but that allows me only to add 60 rules, now I either should find a way to increase the limit of rules per security group, or find a way to attach another security group to the same network  interface (which im not sure how to do that so far) or implement another architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the solution. After you create a security group, and you attach it to the same VPC where the network interface for the instance is, and the same region, etc. Then, you go to network interfaces, right click, or select and click the action button, you click the Change Security Group, but this is tricky, you will think that you can only change from one to another group, but if you press CTRL and hold, you can select two or three groups and then click save, that will attach those security groups to the same interface.